# Jenkins: Process spawning error on windows machine

Tags: python, winforms, jenkins, process

I am automating an testing applications suite from jenkins, for this purpose I have written python code to execute my batch and shell script (testing application) on Jenkins windows and linux system. But when i am executing the jenkins build (provided the path of python script in execute windows batch command in build step), its throwing Spawning processes from build. I have done some google search and found that setting BUILD_ID=doNotfailme and providing the JAVA_ARGS as -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=truewould be a help in resolving, tried the same but still getting the same issue. 
Any help is highly appriciated

Comment: Please paste exact error msg from Jenkins console.

Comment: 00:46:03 Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information